# Still Confused with implementing OAuth to secure REST APIs

Tags: java, security, rest, oauth, jboss

I have been struggling for a while to secure my REST APIs. I have read a lot about `OAuth 2.0` and related libraries  like [Oltu](https://oltu.apache.org/), [KeyCloak](http://keycloak.jboss.org/) but still confused with how to do it.
I will walk through what I understand so far and point my confusions

For a client to access the protected resource `/resource`, the client must have a registered with `Authorization Server` and gained `Access Token`. right?

Lets say I have a following endpoint

```
POST /register
{
‘email’: ‘register_me@yourserver.com'
}
```

and gets the following

```
clientId: <some_client_id>
clientSecret: <some_client_secret>
```

*My confusion*

1. Do I need to store clientId and clientSecret at my Server database against this email? I guess yes
2. What are recommended ways of generating `clientId` and `clientSecret`?

Once client gains `clientId` and `clientSecret`, it calls `/token` endpoint to get an `accessToken`

```
POST /token
{

clientId: <some_client_id>
clientSecret: <some_client_secret>  
}
```

and get the following

```
accessToken: <some_valid_access_token>
```

*My Confusion*

1. Does client gives call to `/token` or `/register` endpoint redirects to `/token`?
2. Do I need to store `accessToken` in database?

Once client has `accessToken`, it will call protected resource endpoint `/resource` to get some data

```
Bearer: <some_valid_access_token>  # as part of header
GET /resource
```

and gets some data from sever

My Confusion

1. The server validates the token to make sure the caller has access to the data
2. Do I need to validate the token against what I have in DB every time? It will be too-infeficent
3. What are recommended ways of generating `accessTokens`?

With all these confusions around, I thought there would be some libraries who does most of the boilerplate work for us, but I failed to get one simple example.
If you have done something similar, can you please guide me to resources?

Thanks